# no font could be found for family "CM Roman" error

Tags: r, fonts

I am plotting rolling correlations using `chart.RollingCorrelation` from `PerformanceAnalytics` package. I want to use "CM Roman" font for the title of the plot as it looks the same like latex's default font. The following code is to reproduce the error:

```
library("extrafont")
library("fontcm")
font_install("fontcm")
loadfonts()

set.seed(2)
x<-ts(rnorm(100), start=c(1,1900))
y<-ts(rnorm(100), start=c(1,1900))
chart.RollingCorrelation(x,y,width=12, ylab="")
title(main= "x and y", family="CM Roman")
```

I checked that "CM Roman" font is registered by `fonts()`. However, it throws to me the following error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In title(main = "x and y", family = "CM Roman") :
  no font could be found for family "CM Roman"
2: In title(main = "x and y", family = "CM Roman") :
  no font could be found for family "CM Roman"
3: In title(main = "x and y", family = "CM Roman") :
  no font could be found for family "CM Roman"
```

Any thought why it gives me that error?

Comment: I had the same problem and eventually found that it was caused by the difference between quartzFonts and pfdFonts. If you execute ``quartzFonts()`` you'll find that ``CM Roman`` is not listed. The [R documentation of quartz Fonts](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/quartzFonts.html) gives the impression that you can register a font as a quartz font. For me, not only exporting my plots and not printing them solved the issue.